# Using and UPDATE Trigger to Modify the Row Being Updated

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have an employee table (em) that contains, among other things, a floor Id (fl_id) and room Id (rm_id). In certain circumstances (when em_loc_cnt = 0) I want to set the em record's fl_id and rm_id to null. Below is my code so far.

I am not sure how to refer to the fl_id & rm_id in the commented line. Will I run into issues because this trigger is being called as a result of the em record being updated and I am updating that same record in the trigger?

Suggestions?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [sysobjects] WHERE [name] = 'em_upd_self_serv_t' AND [type] = 'TR')
  BEGIN
    DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[em_upd_self_serv_t]
 END
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[em_upd_self_serv_t]
  ON [dbo].[em]
  AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @em_id VARCHAR(35),
          @em_loc_cnt INT;

  SET @em_id = (SELECT em_id FROM inserted);
  SET @em_loc_cnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM emlocs WHERE em_id = @em_id);

  IF (@em_loc_cnt = 0) 
    BEGIN
      -- I want to set the fl_id and the rm_id to NULL
    END
END;
```

Comment: For SQL Server **2005** and newer, I'd always recommend using the new, focused catalog view like `sys.triggers` instead of using the old, deprecated `sysobjects` and having to specify the type of object you're looking for....

Comment: Could you name your columns a little more obscurely and less meaningfully, please? Also, your trigger is going to fall over if an update affects more than one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fundamental flaw is that you seem to expect the trigger to be fired **once per row** - this is **NOT** the case in SQL Server. Instead, the trigger fires **once per statement**, and the pseudo table `Inserted` might contain **multiple rows**.

Given that that table might contain multiple rows - which one do you expect will be selected here??

```
SET @em_id = (SELECT em_id FROM inserted);
```

It's undefined - you might get the values from arbitrary rows in `Inserted`.

You need to rewrite your entire trigger with the knowledge the `Inserted` **WILL** contain multiple rows! You need to work with set-based operations - don't expect just a single row in `Inserted` !

You need to change your code to something like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE [name] = 'em_upd_self_serv_t')
    DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[em_upd_self_serv_t]
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[em_upd_self_serv_t]
  ON [dbo].[em]
  AFTER UPDATE
AS
   UPDATE dbo.em
   SET fl_id = NULL, rm_id = NULL
   FROM Inserted i
   WHERE em_id = i.em_id
     AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.emlocs WHERE em_id = i.em_id)
```

Comment: ...AND em_loc_cnt = 0?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: better now? :-)

Comment: I think so. :-) It's not the syntax I would use (`UPDATE em FROM em INNER JOIN inserted`) but that's a different story. :-)